# Как обновить базу данных MySQL, C#?

Tags: c#, mysql

Подключил базу, создал контекст, модели, затем пишу enable-migrations, add-migration - всё нормально
Ввожу update-database - выдает ошибку "Входная строка имела неверный формат", как исправить?...

(При запуске проекта выдается та же самая ошибка)

```
     static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DatabaseContext context = new DatabaseContext();
            
        var group = new Group()
        {
            Name = "Gruppa1",
            Year = 2002,
        };

        //При запуске проекта та же самая ошибка в этом месте
        context.Groups.Add(group);
        context.SaveChanges();

        Console.WriteLine("Группа = ", group.Name);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Подключал так:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="conn" connectionString="Database=newdb;Data Source=localhost;User Id=root;Password=password1122;Integrated Security=True" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Контекст:

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration))]

public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    public DatabaseContext() : base("conn")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Group> Groups { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Song> Songs { get; set; }
}
```

Модели:

```
public class Group
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Song> Songs { get; set; } 
}

public class Song
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int GroupId { get; set; }

    public virtual Group Group { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: MySQL имеет параметр `Integrated Security`? Где вы смотрели, как составить строку соединения к этой СУБД? | [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-connections-string.html)

Comment: Куда именно вы пишете `Update-Database`?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, пробовал другие строки подключения - та же проблема, убирал Integrated Security, добавлял Persist Security Info, либо убирал всех их - не работает...

Comment: @bearpro, туда же, куда и enable-migrations и add-migration  - консоль диспетчера пакетов

Comment: Нет такого понятия: "не работает". Есть конкретная ошибка, с точным описанием проблемы.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, выражайтесь как хотите, сути не меняется

Answer (score 0):

Возможно не может найти базу. Попробуйте другие строки подключения. Вот строка для MySQL.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="conn" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" connectionString="server=localhost;UserId=root;Password=password1;database=mobiledb;CharSet=utf8;Persist Security Info=True" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Такую тоже пробовал, не работает почему-то...